# Python - UserWarning messages loading WSDL into Zeep client

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

I'm attempting to create a client with the zeep python library from a local WSDL file and getting the errors below.

```
/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py:352: UserWarning: The wsdl:message for '{http://www.example.com/CoreApi}SubmitRequest_InputMessage' contains an invalid part ('parameters'): invalid xsd type or elements
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py:352: UserWarning: The wsdl:message for '{http://www.example.com/CoreApi}SubmitRequest_OutputMessage' contains an invalid part ('parameters'): invalid xsd type or elements
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/zeep/wsdl/definitions.py:144: UserWarning: The wsdl:operation 'SubmitRequest' was not found in the wsdl:portType '{http://www.example.com/CoreApi}ICoreApiService'
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/zeep/proxy.py", line 97, in __getitem__
    return self._operations[key]
KeyError: 'SubmitRequest'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    client.service.SubmitRequest()
  File "/zeep/proxy.py", line 88, in __getattr__
    return self[key]
  File "/zeep/proxy.py", line 99, in __getitem__
    raise AttributeError("Service has no operation %r" % key)
AttributeError: Service has no operation 'SubmitRequest'
```

I checked the WSDL and found these elements but don't have much experience working with WSDL or XSD files. I've edited some values since I don't think I can post the full WSDL online. It looks like the operation and parameters are correct based on looking at other WSDLs online and I tried uploading to SoapUI and created a project with no issues.

Any thoughts for what could be causing these messages?

```xml
...
  <wsdl:message name="SubmitRequest_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitRequest" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="SubmitRequest_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubmitRequestResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
...
<wsdl:portType name="ICoreApiService">
    <wsdl:operation name="SubmitRequest">
      <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://www.example.com/SubmitRequest" message="tns:SubmitRequest_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://www.example.com/SubmitRequestResponse" message="tns:SubmitRequest_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
...
```

Code:

```py
from zeep import Client

wsdl='wsdl/CoreApi.wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl)
client.service.SubmitRequest()
```

Python version: 3.9.1
Zeep version: 4.0.0

Comment: Are there any imports or includes in the WSDL file? Something that SoapUI can resolve while zeep might not?!

Comment: @Bogdan yes it does have a list of imports under the wsdl:types -> xsd:schema tags. The WSDL came with quite a few XSD files.

Comment: It might be a red herring as zeep seems to support imports https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/internals_wsdl.html, but if SoapUI doesn't fail or complain about the WSDL, then it means the WSDL and all imported resources are OK, so it might be worth investigating if this is the issue by building one WSDL with everything included and see if zeep likes it better.